# Access Denied when activating Web application Features in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I got the folloiwng exception while activating a web application feature using Stsadm:

```
Access denied!  Only SRP admin can remove property or section.
```

I have no ideas what a SRP admin is.  I'm also at a loss to explain what kind of access does it need.  The account I'm log into the box has the maximum access possible, and I would assume that stsadm runs all its commands as the super user.  Googling didn't reveal much either.

Any help would be appreciated.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2008/05/05/shared-services-administration-for-the-default-ssp.aspx):

> The account that you use to run, must be granted Personalization rights in Shared Services Administration for the Default SSP.
>
> Go to Central Administration
>   Click on SSP-Public
>   Click on Personalization services permissions
>   Add the account and grant Manage user profiles

Comment: I read and followed that site before.  I have every permission for that account in the Shared Service Rights checked.  However I'm still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

What feature are you trying to activate (if it's not a custom feature of course)? What is corresponding application pool identity? Are you farm administrator? If not, try to add yourself to farm admins. Also be sure you do "Run as administrator" when launching cmd for stsadm. If all this will not help, try to add your application pool identity to farm administrators.